# Getting a RecursionError in a python class

Tags: python

I have a Product class defined in Python as below:

```
class Product:
    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.price

    @price.setter
    def price(self, value):
        if value < 10:
            raise ValueError("price can't be negative")
        self.price = value
```

When I try to set the price attribute of a new instance of Product (prod):

```
prod = Product()
prod.price = 25
print(prod.price)
```

I get an error saying:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: You are trying to get/set a property value by getting/setting the property which in turn tries to get/set the property value by getting/setting the property which in turn...

Comment: Your getter and setter calls themselves recursively:  `return self.price`  `self.price = value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recursion occurs here:

```
@price.setter
def price(self, value):
    self.price = value
```

which `self.price =` will trigger the same `price()` function as you make it a setter. The better (i.e., more conventional) way is to use `self._price` to hold your value.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

```
    self.price = value
```

This is a recursive reference to the setter itself.  Look up how to write a setter; you'll see the problem.  You need to refer to the pseudo-private variable:

```
    self._price = value
```

Comment: Thanks. make sense to me now.